# how to store data on client machine in Electron.js?

Tags: database, electron, sheetjs

I am working on an electron project to keep inventory of a warehouse but I want to store the data on the client-side (on the client's desktop/laptop) and not on a cloud database. How do I do this? Is using an xlsx file a good idea to store the data. As it will come with an added bonus as the user can read the data outside the app if they want to in an excel sheet.

P. S: even if xslx is a way I would like to know other possible ways so I can choose which is more comfortable for me. Thank you.

Edit: sorry I forgot to mention that I might also have to store images in the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have plenty of option. You can store json file and read it when application boot up. As this is node js related thing I would suggest you to use [electron store](https://github.com/sindresorhus/electron-store)

And xlsx is a good choice but that may be overkill if the thing you are storing is too simple. On windows you can store some settings in registry too. But I prefer the config version.

I have also used sqlite3 database for some app. In Android I believe many app uses sqlite approach to store local database.

Comment: JSON seems to be the best option for my use case but I also might have images to store so I would like to know if there's a way to do that with JSON. If not then what are the best options. I m sorry for not mentioning the images in the original question.

Comment: @Odasaku for this you save the image and  save its name in json file so you can refer to it later. I think that is best option.

Comment: Oh that was a silly question by me, sorry. Thanks a lot.